# Why Gun.js duplicate messages in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, gun

I'm implementing gun.js in react application.But messages are duplicated on each render, and on each update. Can someone help to figure out what's wrong with my code.

this my code .

```
import Gun from "gun/gun";
import { IGunChain, IGunInstance } from "gun/types";

class GunService {
public gun: IGunInstance<any> | undefined;
public messageListener:
| IGunChain<any, IGunInstance<any>, IGunInstance<any>, "messages">
| undefined;

  constructor() {
     this.gun = Gun("http://localhost:4000" + "/gun");
     this.messageListener = this.gun.get("messages");
   }

   public sendMessage(message: any) {
   this.messageListener?.set(message);
   }
 }
export const gunServices = new GunService();
```

then in my component : get message on each new update

```
   useEffect(() => {
     gunServices.messageListener?.map().on((message) => {
     setMessages((prevMessage) => [...prevMessage, message]);
   });
  }, []);
```

send message  function

```
      const onSendMessage = () => {

       const message = {
       senderUsername: "John Doe",
       senderId: "Doe---id",
       receiverUsername: "John Doe",
       receiverId: "zizou_id",
       message: messageValue,
       date: Date.now().toLocaleString(),
       time: Date.now().toLocaleString(),
    };

     gunServices.sendMessage(message);
     setMessageValue("");
  };
```

Comment: surely its because you're spreading the old value here `setMessages((prevMessage) => [...prevMessage, message]);`
 instead of  ` setMessages( [message]);`

Comment: I tried it but , the new updated message is not added to the message array .

Comment: can you provide examples of the duplicated  output and the expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My simple fix for that was add useRef()

```
   import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react"; 

   useEffect(() => {
     if (loaded.current !== false) return; // Added

     gunServices.messageListener?.map().once().on((message) => {
     setMessages((prevMessage) => [...prevMessage, message]);

     loaded.current = true; // Added
   });
  }, []);
```